# How is temperature changes implemented in a molecular dynamics simulation?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, atomistic-simulation, temperature

I copied my question to this community as the advice of a user on [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/735128/how-is-temperature-changes-implemented-in-a-molecular-dynamics-simulation)

MD simulations are always associated with a temperature that represents the natural state of a system.

However, some techniques, like Simulated Annealing Molecular Dynamics where temperature fluctuates up and down to allow the system to escape local minima, use a non-constant temperature.

In such a case, how is this applied to the system?

I found a very [closely related question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/432470/how-do-we-take-temperature-into-account-in-ab-initio-molecular-dynamics-simulati), but the answer goes beyond my knowledge. If I am looking at Langevin dynamics, is it accurate to say that the temperature is being applied primarily as an increase in particle acceleration?

Comment: It's done with a thermostat in the same way a constant temperature simulation is performed. It's just that in simulated annealing, the target temperature varies over some schedule. Here is a good place to start on learning about thermostats: https://home.gwu.edu/~yxzhao/ResearchNotes/ResearchNote007Thermostat.pdf

Comment: @HaydenS Thank you! This is a great resource, the explanations ramp up nicely from basic to more advanced descriptions.

Comment: @HaydenS are you able to expand that comment into an answer? It has been occupying space in the unanswered queue for almost 7 months, even though it looks like Paul got a satisfactory "answer" from you :)

Answer (score 1):

> "It's done with a thermostat in the same way a constant temperature simulation is performed. It's just that in simulated annealing, the target temperature varies over some schedule. Here is a good place to start on learning about thermostats: see [here](https://home.gwu.edu/%7Eyxzhao/ResearchNotes/ResearchNote007Thermostat.pdf)"

That [comment by Hayden S](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/9922/how-is-temperature-changes-implemented-in-a-molecular-dynamics-simulation#comment20990_9922) seem to have been satisfactory to the OP, but if someone wants to write a more detailed answer, I'd be happy to delete this Community Wiki.